# Compile swift framework with 3rd-party libraries

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

Let's say I have a custom framework with lots of functionalities, written in Swift.
This framework let's call it *'MyFramework'*, uses some 3rd party libraries, like Firebase, SDWebimage, PromiseKit etc. I integrated these with **CocoaPods**.
Our goal is to compile our framework on my machine, then give the produced **.framework** file to the customer, who can integrate it into his project.

It is very important to precompile the framework, because we don't want to allow the customers, to see/modify our code.

This is working, but the problem is, that for example if our customer uses Firebase in his project too (installed with CocoaPods too), then he will get lots of warnings, like this:

**Class XY is implemented in both MyProject and MyFramework. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.**

Is it possible to somehow build my framework without the concrete implementations of these libraries, and get them from the customer's installed Pods?

Another possible solution that I tried, is to put all dependencies into the framework and try to reference them from the customer's project. But then the compiler said, that can't reference these dependencies, which is funny because if I install all of them again to the project it will say that duplicated dependencies.

What would be the best way to compile the framework, but also use these Pods in it?

Comment: How does your framework pull in the third party libraries?

Comment: With CocoaPods. I tried to use the pre-compiled Firebase libraries, but I got compilation errors.
So if is it possible I would stick to CocoaPods.

Comment: Via the [dependency](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency) field in the Podspec file? I'm using this field to determine the frameworks that _MyFramework_ relies on. When it gets integrated in another app, CocoaPods is smart enough to not import dependencies twice.

Comment: I thought Podspec is only needed if you want to create your own Pod. In my case, I have to install the Pods before compiling the framework, because I don't want to allow anyone to view the source code. Sorry, I if don't understand something, but this is a bit unclear for me now.

Comment: Ah, my bad. When you said that you integrate your 3rd party libraries through CocoaPods, I thought you were distributing your framework through CocoaPods as well.